# Understanding Router Resources in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Let's suppose my Ember.js App has a router that looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('posts');
});
```

I understand [from the guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) that this means that I get two routes: `PostsRoute`, and `PostsIndexRoute`, and that `PostsRoute` is the parent.

Here's my `PostsRoute`:

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    this.store.find('posts');
  },

  afterModel: function (posts) {
    var promises = posts.map(function (post) {
      return post.get('author'); // some async relationship
    });

    return Em.RSVP.Promise.all(promises);
  }
});
```

And my `PostsIndexRoute`:

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.modelFor('posts');
  }
});
```

Since my `PostsRoute` is the parent of `PostsIndexRoute`, I'm expecting that it's `model` hooks are always resolved, even when transitioning from somewhere else in my application to 'posts' (e.g. via a `transitionTo` or `link-to`). This does not seem to be the case. What exactly is the relationship between a `<Resource>` and `<Resource>Index` route? I'm a bit confused as to why you'd need both.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have Ember automatically call the `PostsIndexRoute`'s `model` hook you have to declare your resource with a second argument. Having a second argument indicates that it should have child routes (`index` being the one provided by default).

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('posts', function(){});
})
```

[Here's a bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lifas/3/edit) that demonstrates the behaviour.

Comment: For reference, the Ember docs describe this behaviour in the "NOTE:" here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_resources